# Perl 6 blocks on awaiting killed Proc::Async

Tags: raku

I have a perl6 program that runs a external program via `Proc::Async` and tries to read its `stdout`. It's possible that the portion of the code that is supposed to read the stdout somehow fails to do so, but other parts of the program will actually kill the external process in order to clean things up. However, after killing such process, and then await the promise, it blocks forever..., how can I avoid perl6 from blocking on awaiting a killed `Proc::Async` whose `stdout` is piped but not consumed? I think the following snippet illustrate the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6
#

my $proc = Proc::Async.new(<cat /dev/urandom>);
my $supply = $proc.stdout(:bin);
my $promise = $proc.start;

$proc.ready.then: {
    shell <<ps auxf | grep [u]random>>;
    put "Terminating process {$_.result} …";
    $proc.kill(SIGTERM);
}
sleep 1;
if shell(<<ps auxf | grep [u]random>>).exitcode ≠ 0 {
    put "processed killed!";
}

put "awaiting $proc ({$proc.command}) …";
await $promise;  # <--- blocked here :(
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Promise` returned from `start` is only kept once any obtained `Supply` of the output streams has delivered all of its events. This means one can assume that all output has been delivered by the time the `Promise` is kept, which overall greatly simplifies working with `Proc::Async` (without this behavior, we'd likely see a good number of buggy programs that lose output). However, if that `Supply` is never tapped, then there's no way for that to happen, thus the hang.

The solution is to `.tap` the `stdout` `Supply` without providing any callback:

```
$proc.stdout(:bin).tap;
```

Which will simply discard the output.